# Is there a spring-data module for EMC Documentum?

Tags: spring-data, documentum

I'm using EMC Documentum content server 7.1 as my backend.
I have a lot of java boilerplate code which interract with the backend using DFC.
I'm wandering if a spring-data module exists for my use case.

Comment: there is announcemnt of something but I didn't had my hands on it

Comment: By reading this tweet I thought it was already available : https://twitter.com/conrado_poole/status/727603067617607680

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a project at github:

https://github.com/Enterprise-Content-Management/spring-data-dctm

and body has to be at least 30 characters so this should be more than enough. thank you SO! :-)

Comment: Thank you for the link. I don't understand "and body has to be at least 30 characters so this should be more than enough".

Comment: When you answer a question your response needs to have at least 30 characters, so I had to put something into it.