# Is there a spring-data UPDATED module for EMC Documentum in 2021?

Tags: java, spring, documentum, dfc, dctm

The same question here:
[Is there a spring-data module for EMC Documentum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37071509/is-there-a-spring-data-module-for-emc-documentum)

The answer is yes, but the project seems to be stucked at 6 years ago.
It's dependency is Documentum 7.2.

NO MORE UPDATES AFTER FIRST RELEASE 0.0.1

We are using documenum 16.7!

Is there any alternative?

Comment: You already answered it yourself. There isn't.

Comment: There were few changes to DFC since 7.2, so I am pretty sure that the code still works.

Comment: @KarolBe: if I add spring-data-documentum in pom.xml it asks me for com.emc.documentum.dfc:dfc:jar:7.2.... I'm not free to choose, I have to use dfc 16.7. Is there any safe workaround?

Comment: Since spring-data is open source you can clone the repo, modify pom.xml and change dependency version from 7.2 to 16.7, rebuild and use.